# android - make textView invisible

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

When my app starts, the user needs to touch on the screen before the real action starts. I have a `textView` which gives the hint to touch the screen.

After the screen is touched, I want the text to get *invisible*. Right now the `textView` never disappears and always stays in the front.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener
{       
    public boolean touched = false;
    TextView mMyView;

    public void onTouch() 
    {
        mMyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
        touched = true;                 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                       
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        mMyView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        if(touched == true) 
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not initialize the touch listener. Where u initialize it ?

Comment: It recognizes the touch, but the textView stays. Is it set up false then?

Comment: Try to set visibility as INVISIBLE instead of GONE

Comment: @Manoj I tried it, but the text still stays visible

Comment: initialize the text view inside the onCreate.try this and let me know. One more thing while touching, Is the method onTouch() called. Make sure that it is called.

Comment: @Nithinlal I edited my code. Still the same problem

Comment: `INVISIBLE` will just let your textView disappear, but the space it needs is still in "use". GONE will also remove the space, so set INVISIBLE instead of GONE will not fix your problem.

Comment: Is the id of your TextView `textView6` correct? You need to use the view id from your layout xml that you set via `setContentView`

Comment: Okay, but why doesn't it even disappear?

Comment: @JoeS : method `onTouch()` is not calling from your activity

Comment: try `if(tv.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){ tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);}`

Comment: and onTouch is not overriden. You should call it in onCreate()

Comment: and why you are sure that the method `onTouch` is executed? You have made no part of check here like a Toast or a Log

Comment: It is part of my code, and it works, the only problem I have is that the textView always is visible

Comment: @Joe S check my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Always use `if(something)` if you want to see if it's `true/false` instead of writing `if(something == true)`   [something is a boolian assigned with value true.]

2.If you point your views xml to a method using `android:onClick` like below,

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:onClick="onTouch" />
```

.
    What's the point of implementing `OnGestureListener`?

If i do this `onCreate` i initialize my view

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

3.If i really want a touch i will do this

```
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // ... Respond to touch events --> tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true; // if you return false with this then the listener will not be called for the subsequent ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP string of events.
    }
});
```

4. Now you can see in the 3rd ones parameter there is a `MotionEvent`, you can identify the motion  `ACTION_DOWN` , `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP`

Now think have you ever used them. You got an idea in your head about a touch so tried to use touch events .. But you don't use them. So it does the same as what `onClickListner` does in your case. If you want motions use that 3rd one i gave.

But simply you can use

```
 // view is the background layout
    myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Do something here --> Hide your text  tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Those view `onClickListner` or `setOnTouchListener` you can directly use them inside `onCreate`  or keep them inside a method and you can call that method from `onCreate`. Why to keep a boolean? It's nothing major

Note i considered  myView as the background layout not your textView , background is the one you click / touch

Answer (score 1):

So now you changed the questions code several times and I hope it´s the final change. Only than my answer could help.

You have done this in your `onCreate()`:

```
 if(touched == true) 
        {
           tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);           
        }
```

But this is executed directly and has nothing to do with you `onTouch()` method. Let´s assume your `onTouch()` works correctly. Make the `TextView` *global*:

```
TextView mMyView;
```

initialize it in `onCreate()`:

```
mMyView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
```

and then hide it in `onTouch()`:

```
onTouch(View view){

mMyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

But you have to be sure that your method `onTouch()` works. You can make a `Toast` or a Log to check. You have to be sure that:

-The `TextView` is inside your layout xml that you set with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);`

-The `onTouch()` method is declared in your `TextView`'s xml attribute

`android:onClick="onTouch"`

and set clickable of your `TextView` to true:

`android:clickable="true";`

### EDIT

If you implement `onGestureListener()` I guess the touch event is consumed by the listener and your `TextView` did *not* recognize `onTouch()`. If you don´t do any gesture detection in your activity, then remove this implementation.

Comment: I tried as you said and edited my code. No change of the problem

Comment: are you sure that you implemented it correctly? Be aware of capital letters. You must name the onTouch Method in your xml identical `onTouch` small o in xml and activity.

Comment: and if your code is updated you forget something `onTouch(View v)` ....also, deinstall your app, clean the project and reinstall it...

Comment: and set android:clickable="true" in your xml TextView

Comment: @Opiatefuchs why you check `true == true`  anyway its `true`

Comment: @Charuka...as stated in my introducing sentence, that´s only what the questioneer posted in his question.: **You have done this in your onCreate()**

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if screen was touched in `onCreate()` which is called only once at the start of the activity. Initialize TextView globally and set its visibility inside `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`
Also your `onTouch()` isn;t correct. You should override  `public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{       
    public boolean touched = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                       
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                touched = true; 
                tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `OnGestureListener` add a `setOnTouchListener` in your root view of your activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rlTestView"/>
```

For example `rlTestView` is your activity's root layout id, then use below code in your `oncreate` method

```
((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlTestView)).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            tv.setVisibility(View.GONE); 

            return true;
        }
    });`
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the code below on the `onCreate` method and yes set the `visibility` as `GONE` instead of invisible. Also state the current *visibilty* of the `TextView` in the `onTouch` then set it to

```
  tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Then one solution is that instead of applying visibility to the textview, apply to the layout and hide the layout.